# Do not redirect user after auth failed with BasicAuthenticationFilter

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have two way user can authenticate on my system. Standart with login password and using BasicAuthentication for API calls. When standart auth failed, I send redirect to login page, but when BasicAuth failed I want to return json response.

I also have custom AccessDecisionManager defined and after WebExpressionVoter returns access_denied, the AccessDeniedException is being thrown and in rest client I see html code of main page.
How should I configure my spring security, to return json response?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement custom `org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandler` which sends JSON response as you need from its `handle` method. The `handle` is called automatically whenever `AccessDecisionManager` denies access.

You then add instance of your class as a bean in the Spring Security configuration and refer to it from your API's `<security:http>` definition as follows:

```
 <security:http pattern="/API/**">
     <security:http-basic />
     <security:access-denied-handler ref="myDeniedHandler"/>
 </security:http>
```